# Xamarin.forms error message - understanding position number?

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is the error message:

> **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException** was thrown.
> Position 158:37. Empty value string in markup expression

What does the position number mean? Line 158 position 37 or line 37 position 158?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException was thrown. Position 158:37.

This means your error is occurred at **Line 158 position 37**.

[image]